# React-native - npm-start not working - giving error with metro - events.js:183 throw er

Tags: android, linux, react-native, npm, npm-start

I am trying to run a react native application in Android from Linux server, now I am getting this error when trying to start npm server with `npm-start'`.

```
> test0app@0.0.1 start /home/lenovot430/Documents/ReactProjects/test0app
> node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start

┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                              │
│  Running Metro Bundler on port 8081.                                         │
│                                                                              │
│  Keep Metro running while developing on any JS projects. Feel free to        │
│  close this tab and run your own Metro instance if you prefer.               │
│                                                                              │
│  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                    │
│                                                                              │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8081
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1360:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1401:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1485:7)
    at Promise (/home/lenovot430/Documents/ReactProjects/test0app/node_modules/metro/src/index.js:253:20)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/lenovot430/Documents/ReactProjects/test0app/node_modules/metro/src/index.js:252:14)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/home/lenovot430/Documents/ReactProjects/test0app/node_modules/metro/src/index.js:46:24)
    at _next (/home/lenovot430/Documents/ReactProjects/test0app/node_modules/metro/src/index.js:66:9)
    at <anonymous>
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test0app@0.0.1 start: `node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the test0app@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/lenovot430/.npm/_logs/2019-04-29T09_09_45_424Z-debug.log
```

If I try 'react-native run-android', app is stuck at loading screen.

The fixes I tried for fixing it

1. Removed Node Modules, cleaned caches and installed again.

   `rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean --force && npm install`
2. Uninstalled and Reinstalled Watchman

   `brew uninstall watchman
    brew link pcre
    brew install --HEAD watchman
    brew install watchman`
3. Cloned watchman repo and tried version 4.9.0

   `$ git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git
   $ cd watchman
   $ git checkout v4.9.0  # the latest stable release
   $ ./autogen.sh
   $ ./configure
   $ make
   $ sudo make install`

I havent made any configuration changes in the react native app. I tried making a new project with `react-native init`, but in that project also, I am getting the same Error.

My `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "test0app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.4",
    "babel-jest": "^24.7.1",
    "jest": "^24.7.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: `react-native run-android` causing this error?

Comment: If I use `react-native run-android`, the app is stuck at Loading from Screen. `npm-start` is giving me this error.

Comment: may be its because there is another program running on that port, check are there other `command shells` or program running through that port

Comment: That I had checked already. No service was running at that port. Look at the error, service started on the port, then it hit some error.

Answer (score 0):

You have the error, `Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8081`, which means "Address in use".

Sometimes the web server that is launched with the bundler fails to tear down properly, and thus it keeps port 8081 locked. You can find the rogue process using:

```
lsof -wni tcp:8081
```

And then kill it via its PID

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

I have to do this, once a fortnight or so.